# Linux Duplicate Buffer?

Tags: c++, c, linux, debian, buffer

Right now my setup looks like this:

`command1 | buffer | command2`

I want to have a 3rd command, "command3" read from the buffer as well. My attempted workaround was to start the process as a child process and simply pipe the command1 | buffer | command3. The issue with that is, not only does it lead to read errors of command1, command2 would also "steal" data from command3 or otherway around. Basicly what i want to achieve is a `tee` like behaviour but instead of forwarding it into a buffer and a file i want to forward it to two buffers, without command2 affecting command3 or vice versa. Kind of like this:

```
command1 | buffer1          | command2
              \
               ---- buffer2 | command3
```

It should also happen simultaneously.

How could i achieve that behaviour? Are there code or non code solutions? 
Edit: I'm working with infinite streams namely audio.

Comment: Have a separate process (like `tee`) that reads from one pipe and writes to 2 or more other pipes?

Comment: doesn't reading "erase" the data so writing to 2 pipes is not possible ? that's how i understand read works. The solution would be to temporarily save the buffer somewhere, but i don't know how that would look like in code.

Comment: The suggestion is for a reader to consume the input pipe and then duplicate the data to two output pipes.

Comment: In pseudocode, `while(more) { read(input, buffer); write(output1, buffer); write(output2, buffer); }`

Comment: in my initial question i forgot to mention i'm working with infinite streams as input and command2 and command3 need to receive the data simultaneously as well. does the same logic still apply ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this on bash.

`echo hello | tee >(echo command1 >&2) | echo command2`

[See this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/96260)

Comment: This is a bash solution, but OP is asking about C/C++

Comment: the answer you linked me helped me out a lot. i didn't know about "pee" from moreutils package. it was exactly what i was looking for thanks.

Comment: Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Using `tee` and bash's command substitution:

Example commands:

```
$ alias command1='perl -e'\''$|=1; CORE::say for qw( a b c )'\' 

$ alias command2='perl -pe'\''$|=1; $_ = "x $_"'\' 

$ alias command3='perl -pe'\''$|=1; $_ = "y $_"'\'
```

Solution:

```
$ exec 3>&1   # dup2(1,3)

$ command1 | tee >( command2 >&3 ) | command3
x a
y a
x b
y b
x c
y c

$ exec 3>&-   # close(3)
```

(Unlike the other answer posted at the same time, this one doesn't assume STDOUT and STDERR are the same.)

(The lines appear to be processed in lockstep by `command2` and `command3`, which can't be guaranteed without additional communication. To even get close, `command1` needs to avoid buffering its output.)

If you wanted a program to do this instead of using a shell, it's simply a case of doing the following in rough details:

1. For `i` in `2`, `3`,

   1. Create pipe `pipei`.
   2. Fork.
   3. If in the child,

      1. Close the write end of `pipei`.
      2. Tie the read end of `pipei` to fd 1.
      3. Execute `commandi`.
   4. Close the read end of `pipei`.
   5. Set the close-on-exec flag of the write end of `pipei` to true.
2. Write to both pipes.

Comment: This is a bash solution, but OP is asking about C/C++

Comment: i forgot to mention that the input i use is infinite and i need the buffers to be processed simultaneously. from your example it seems like command 2 gets processed before command 3.

Comment: "Infinite" streams works fine. And both `command2` and `command3` get the input at the same time (or as close as possible). There is buffering causing the data to be sent in chunks, which you can disable. If you want the lines to be processed in lockstep, they will need to communicate with each other or with `command1`.